# Ellipse - relation between a and b such that $F_1P \perp F_2P$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Consider the ellipse $\displaystyle \dfrac{x^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ with foci $F_1 (-e, 0)$ and $F_2 (e, 0)$ (where $e$ is the linear eccentricity).

What is the relation between $a$ and $b$ so that we get points $P$ on the ellipse satisfying $F_1P \perp F_2P$?

I'd be glad for any hint to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is such a point $P$ on the ellipse  iff the system
$${x^2\over a^2}+{y^2\over b^2}=1,\qquad x^2+y^2=e^2=a^2-b^2\tag{1}$$
has real solutions $(x,y)$. From $(1)$ one obtains
$$x^2={a^2(a^2-2b^2)\over a^2-b^2},\qquad y^2={b^4\over a^2-b^2}\ .$$
This gives real $(x,y)$ iff $a\geq\sqrt{2}\,b$.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

HINT :

If $F_1P\perp F_2P$, then the $P$ is on the circle whose diameter is $F_1F_2$.

Comment: Ah! So P is on a circle following Thales' Theorem. And the ratio of those circles is $F_1F_2/2 = e$ (linear eccentricity). Then for those $P$ I have $MP = e$. But what does that tell me about the relation between $b$ and $e$?

Comment: @Vazrael : Since the coordinates of the points both on the circle and on $y$ axis are $(0,\pm e)$, we have $e\ge b$.